# How do I move a component object to a global object?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am currently working on a music player, I have a "tracks" component that retrieves an ajax request that displays a list of songs. onClick I have that song data go into an object that I am attempting to send to a component that is completely unrelated which is the audio player. What is the best way to send this data to the audio player?

## Track

```
<template>
<div id="tracks">
  <h5 class="header">Top tracks</h5>

  <select name="range" v-model="range">
    <option value="day">Day</option>
    <option value="week">Week</option>
    <option value="month">Month</option>
    <option value="year">Year</option>
    <option value="life">Life</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <div id="top-tracks">
  <div id="track"  v-for="(track) in tracks" :key='track.id'>
    <img @click="currentTrack(track)" class="cover" :src="'https://api.napster.com/imageserver/v2/albums/' + track.albumId  + '/images/500x500.jpg'">

    <div class=content-name><p>{{track.name}}</p></div>
    <div class="artist-name"><p>{{track.artistName}}</p></div>
  </div>
  </div>

</div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'Tracks',
  components: {
  },
  data () {
    return {
      tracks: [],
      track: {
        name: "",
        artist: "",
        album: "",
        song: ""
      },
      range: 'day'
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.trackData();
  },
  watch: {
    range : function () {
      this.trackData();
    }
  },
  methods: {
    trackData: function () {
      axios.get('http://api.napster.com/v2.2/tracks/top?apikey=YTkxZTRhNzAtODdlNy00ZjMzLTg0MWItOTc0NmZmNjU4Yzk4&limit=10&range=' + this.range)
      .then(response => {
        // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
        this.tracks = response.data.tracks
      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e)
      })
    },
    currentTrack: function (track) {
      this.track.name = track.name;
      this.track.artist = track.artistName;
      this.track.album = track.albumId;
      this.track.song = track.href;

    }
  }
}
</script>
```

## Audio Player

```
<template>
  <div id="audio-player">
    <div class="player__inner">

      <current-track class="player__left"/>

      <div class="player__center">
        <player-controls/>
        <player-playback/>
      </div>

      <div class="player__right">
        <!-- <device-picker/> -->
        <!-- <volume-bar/> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import CurrentTrack from './CurrentTrack';
  import PlayerControls from './PlayerControls';
  import PlayerPlayback from './PlayerPlayback';

  export default {
      name: "audio-player",
      components: {
        CurrentTrack,
        PlayerControls,
        PlayerPlayback
      },
      data () {
        return {

        }
      }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You need a vuex: https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your application grows larger and more complex, [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org) will be great to use, but it also introduces concepts such as mutations and actions, which could need some time to wrap your head around. The easier way to achieve what you want is to set the root component's data. Simply set the data property of your root Vue component and retrieve it with `this.$root.$data`. The code will be something like this:

```
new Vue({
  ...
  data: {
    user: ...
  }
})
```